# debug java web application packaged as war file in eclipse

Tags: java, jms, weblogic, war, web-inf

I am new to web applications in java and need a bit of help with this. I have a multi module project set up in eclipse, which also contains WEB-INF/lib directory of the WAR.

In the non-web version i can debug though it fine however when i deploy it to weblogic i am encountering errors which i dont get on my local workspace, so i'm trying to deploy it using tomcat. I installed tomcat and deployed the war file onto it. I see a blank page (which is normal -  essentially the application has a listener, i send it a jms message and that kicks off the process afterwards) but i dont know how to put a break point so i can step though the code - line by line - if this is possible?. Would appreciate some references / reading material.

Comment: You can set up remote debugging with Weblogic/Eclipse: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/remotedebugwls-086628.html